# Xgboost take k best predictions

Tags: xgboost

I have a mission of classification with a lot of classes. I am comparing some ML algorithms for this case and I would like to try xgboost. 
I am writing in python and I am trying to get the best 3 predictions using this algorithm but I couldn't find any method in xgboost API the fits what I want

Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 1):

After fitting the model you can use predict_proba( ) from the [docs here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html)

This returns a numpy array with the probability of each data example being of a given class. The three highest probabilities will be your best 3 predictions.

Answer (score 0):

After processing your data , use `xgb.fit(X,y)` and then `xgb.predict_proba(X_test)`, you will get probabilities of each class for each data point. Next you need to apply **probability calibration** to get somewhat usable probabilities. Then pick your 3 highest probas, and your data point will most likely have a label of one of those classes.